# Increase number each day

Tags: powershell

I need to create a variable in PowerShell that increases with one each day. I'm going to use this variable in an email subject to define the Day Number as part of a test schedule. e.g. "Test - Day 38", when the script runs the next day it must ready "Test - Day 39".

I obviously can't use the date and AddDays, because the count is not limited to the number of days in the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code, `$days` is the result

```
# when counting starts, the first day
$startDate = [datetime]'2014-01-12'

# elapsed days (+ 1 in order to start with "day 1")
$days = [int]((Get-Date) - $startDate).TotalDays + 1

# result string
"Test - Day $days"
```

This code outputs (today)

```
Test - Day 38
```

Comment: As @Vish suggests, using `.Days` is even simpler, casting to `[int]` is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I propose (it *does* involve using the `date` cmdlets):

- When the test first runs, store the runtime in a file. 
  For example:

  ```
  if (!(Test-Path startTime.txt)) {
      get-date | out-file startTime.txt
  }
  ```
- Each time the test runs subsequently, read in the `first_runtime` from the file.
- Subtract the current date (using `get-date`) from `first_runtime`.
- This will have a `.Days` member you can extract to retrieve the number of Days elapsed.

  ```
  Days              : 2
  Hours             : 0
  ...
  ```